# passing futures to whenReady fails

Tags: unit-testing, scala, future, scalatest

I'm trying to write a spec for something using futures, and I'm not sure how I'm supposed to use the `Futures` trait. I have to pass `whenReady` a `FutureConcept`, but I can't find how I should construct one from a `Future`. The documentation reads:

> To make whenReady more broadly applicable, the type of future it
>   accepts is a FutureConcept[T], where T is the type of value promised
>   by the future. Passing a future to whenReady requires an implicit
>   conversion from the type of future you wish to pass (the modeled type)
>   to FutureConcept[T].

From that I understand that I have to write an implicit conversion between a `Future` and a `FutureConcept` (which seems wrong to me, as it seems that should be boilerplate, but it's the only thing I can make of it). I can't figure out how to do that though, the documentation of FutureConcept tells me handily

> See the documentation for trait Futures for the details on the syntax
>   this trait provides for testing with futures.

making me come full circle. The simplest example I cooked up is

```
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

import org.scalatest.WordSpecLike
import org.scalatest.concurrent._

class FutureSpec extends WordSpecLike with Futures {
  "A future" must {
    "be a valid argument for whenReady" in {
      val fut = future { 42 }
      whenReady(fut) { res => s should be 42 }
    }
  }
}
```

That doesn't compile with

> - type mismatch; found : scala.concurrent.Future[Int] required: FutureSpec.this.FutureConcept[?]
> - ';' expected but integer literal found.

what should I be doing differently?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I found the implicit conversions to be present in `ScalaFutures`, not in `Futures`. The class declaration should be

```
class FutureSpec extends WordSpecLike with ScalaFutures
```

Other than that, there are a couple of other errors. FutureSpec should also have `Matchers` mixed in, and `res => s` is a silly typo, and should be `res => res`

Comment: This answer is absolutely right, just to add a bit of clarity: Change 'with Futures' for 'with ScalaFutures'

Comment: That's perfect. Your answer helped me a lot. Cheers!

Comment: Had to use `extends AsyncFunSuite with Matchers with AsyncMockFactory with ScalaFutures`